# MASM Assembly: Storing a floating point

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, masm

I am trying to figure out how to store a floating point into MASM and understand how is it stored. For example, if I have the number:

```
1234.56_10 ;Base 10
```

Where I have to store it and convert it into base 10. What would I have to do to store the `.56` value? I was thinking of storing `1234` first, converting it into base 10; then storing `.56`, also convert it, and to later add them both together.

But the problem I have is with storing `.56`. I don't know how to store it, and I do not know how is it stored into memory. Is it stored as an ASCII character? Or is it stored differently?

Answer (score 7):

There are basically three different floating-point types in MASM:

- **`REAL4`**

  This is the equivalent of C's `float` type, and it is a single-precision floating point value, stored in 4 bytes. It has a range of ±1.7×10<sup>38</sup>, with 6 significant digits.

  The format is (from high bit to low bit): sign bit, 8-bit exponent, 23-bit mantissa. (The leading 1 is implicit.)

  [image]
- **`REAL8`**

  This is the equivalent of C's `double` type, and it is a double-precision floating point value, stored in 8 bytes. It has a range of ±1×10<sup>308</sup>, with 14 significant digits.

  The format is (from high bit to low bit): sign bit, 11-bit exponent, 52-bit mantissa. (The leading 1 is implicit.)

  [image]
- **`TBYTE`**

  This is what the x87 FPU natively stores in its registers (which are implemented as a stack), and is often equivalent to C's `long double` type (if supported by your compiler).

  It is a 10-byte value (which is where the type name comes from), with a range of ±10<sup>4932</sup>, with 18 significant digits.

  The format is (from high bit to low bit): sign bit, 15-bit exponent, 64-bit mantissa, explicit leading 1.

  [image]

<sub>(The images above are taken from the linked Wikipedia articles, licensed via [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).)</sub>

Generally, you will want to use one of the latter two formats, `REAL8` or `TBYTE`, because you always want to use as much precision as possible. Plus, there is no significant speed penalty for using higher-precision types on the x87. (The only way you'll see a speed-up is if you limit the processor to working *only* with single-precision types, and that takes work and is very likely not what you want because of the great loss of precision.)

So let's look at the 64-bit `REAL8` format as an example.

In the real world, floating-point values are often expressed in "scientific notation", which is a base-10 format—*e.g.*, 1.81×10<sup>3</sup>. In computing, a *binary*-based format is used: 1.0110101×2<sup>7</sup>. Essentially, the notation is: mantissa×2<sup>exponent</sup>. (The mantissa is also known as the "fraction" portion.)

As always, the number of bits used to store each component determines the precision of that component. In the 64-bit `REAL8` format, 52 bits are devoted to storing the mantissa (actually, 53 bits, since there is 1 implied bit). This gives you approximately 15 decimal digits worth of precision.

Preceding the mantissa's 52 bits are 11 bits used to store the exponent. The exponent field is *biased* to the middle of the available range, such that negative exponents are effectively smaller than positive exponents. For `REAL8` values, the exponent bits have a bias of 0x3FF.

Finally, the highest-order bit is a sign bit. It is set to 0 if the value is positive, or 1 if the value is negative.

So, the value of +1.0 would have the following representation in `REAL8` format:

```
0 01111111111 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
^ |----^----| |--------------------------^-----------------------|
|      |                                 |
|   exponent                         mantissa
|
sign bit
```

Or, in a simpler hex notation, 0x3FF0000000000000.

For −1.0, everything stays the same, the sign bit just gets flipped:

```
1 01111111111 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
^ |----^----| |--------------------------^-----------------------|
|      |                                 |
|   exponent                         mantissa
|
sign bit
```

The smallest possible value that can be represented in the `REAL8` format has an exponent of 1 and a mantissa of 0 (approximately 2.2×10<sup>-308</sup>):

```
0 00000000001 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
^ |----^----| |--------------------------^-----------------------|
|      |                                 |
|   exponent                         mantissa
|
sign bit
```

There are some tricky things are the special types of values that can be encoded in this format, like infinities, not-a-number (NaN) and denormals, but you really don't need to worry about those. Basically, in the `REAL8` format, the maximum value for the exponent field, 0x7FF, indicates either infinity or [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), while an exponent field set to 0 and a non-zero mantissa indicates a ["denormal" number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number). You'll find a more thorough description of this, and all foregoing information, in Intel's documentation for the x87 FPU (an older version is mirrored [here on John Loomis's site](http://www.johnloomis.org/ece314/notes/fpu/fpu.pdf)).

But in reality, no one thinks about this or does this conversion by hand. You either get your assembler to do it, or you use [a converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/) (there are plenty of others to choose from online; I just search and use whichever one pops up first).

For example, what if we didn't know about the `FLDPI` instruction and wanted to store π as a `REAL8` value? Well, we'd plug in 3.14159, and see that its binary `REAL8` representation is:

```
0 10000000000 1001001000011111100111110000000110111000011001101110
^ |----^----| |--------------------------^-----------------------|
|      |                                 |
|   exponent                         mantissa
|
sign bit
```

Or, in hexadecimal: `0x400921F9F01B866E`. Of course, this is an inexact value, closer to 3.141589999…, but [floating-point is like that](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

As for your question, I think you must be misusing the term "base 10". 1234.5610 is already a base-10 value—no conversion is necessary. If you stored it in `REAL8` format, it would be:

```
0 10000001001 0011010010100011111001110110110010001011010000111001
^ |----^----| |--------------------------^-----------------------|
|      |                                 |
|   exponent                         mantissa
|
sign bit
```

or, equivalently, `0x40934A3E76C8B439`. If you had *that* and wanted to convert it back into the familiar base-10 notation, you'd have to parse the format as I described it throughout this answer. I honestly don't know why you want to do that, but you could now if you really wanted to. I'd use [a converter](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/64bit.html): plug in `40934A3E76C8B439`, click "Rounded", and get back `1234.5610`.

Otherwise, it sounds like you might be trying to re-invent [fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic), which basically stores real/decimal values as integers. You'd store `1234` as one integer, and `5610` as another integer, then combine them. The decimal point's position would be implicit, and you could add it back in for display purposes. See also: [Fixed Point Arithmetic and Tricks (for the x86)](http://x86asm.net/articles/fixed-point-arithmetic-and-tricks/).

Comment: BTW if the question instead is "how to implement such a decimal -> binary FP converter" the answer is "you are in for a world of pain if you want to do it accurately to the last ULP, just call some `strtod` equivalent". To do a somewhat sloppy job instead is way easier (and faster).

Comment: Thanks! That is a lot to process, but it is really helpful. I am taking an assembly class and I was assigned to build a multi-base calculator. So, for example, one of the assignments for the code is to multiply to numbers with different base and output them to an specific base: `ABCD.EF_16 * 1234.56_10 > 10` Here the first one is base 16 and the second is 10, and I have to give the result in base 10. That is what I am trying to do with the number I posted. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @MrGamez22 and can you use the clib, or not? Because as Matteo noted, it's PITA to create correct ASCII -> float/double converter, availability of `std::atof` would make sure your conversion is correct.... hm... now I see `atof`-like functions are always base 10, so as you are supposed to read also things like `ABCD.EF_16`, you are destined to do it on your own. Maybe just do some naive convertor.. parsing string, reading base, finding dot, and the digit on left side of dot is of 1.0 value, then each digit further left is additional *base value, and to the right it is additional /base value.

Comment: @MrGamez22 doing that all (multiplications and summing) in the x87 fpu unit, and storing the final `REAL8` (8B `double` C type), which is widely recognized by other programming languages/ABI.

Comment: @Ped7g I am not allowed to used the clib. Well the teacher did not teach that, so I am sure he won't allow us to use it. And yeah, as you said, I am trying to do that, to find the dot and to read values on the left and the right. But the problem I have is with storing the ones in the right after the dot.

Comment: @MrGamez22 Well, you put 1.0 into FPU stack, put the base value there too (16 for your example), do 1.0/16 (I will call it "digit_value"), and convert digit `E` into 14 (obvious?), and multiply it by that 1/16 digit_value => so you will get value 14/16 in the FPU, keep that around as "sum" ... do another "/base" (division by 16, actually you can precompute 1.0/16 first, and then multiply by that, to avoid divisions) to digit_value, so now digit_value will be 1/16/16 = 1/16*16 = 1/256, and convert digit `F` to 15, multiply that by digit_value => 15/256 and sum it to previous 14/16. + `0xABCD`.

Comment: @MrGamez22 this is far from "production quality", as this naive approach will introduce some rounding errors, but up to 10-13 significant (decimal) digits it should be OK. Then `ABCD.EF_16` = A(10) * 16^3 + B(11) * 16^2 + C(12) * 16^1 + D(13) * 16^0 + E(14) * 16^-1 + F(15) * 16^-2 = 43981.93359375  (`0x40E579BDE0000000` in REAL8 binary data, where exponent is of value 1038 and mantissa starts with 01010111... in binary).

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks, that makes more sense for me. Because I have not used all of the other terminology, I was confused. But this is exactly what I was looking for. One question though, after I get the result of that sum, where do I store it to add it with what was on the left side of the dot, which was `ABCD`? Can I store it into a register like `EAX` and add it to another register that has the value of `1234` stored?

Comment: The old x87 FPU way is, that the there are separate floating point registers, actually working as FP-stack (not as general as eax/ebx/...), so you keep all those values on the FPU stack all the time, until you have the final result, then you "pop" it out from FP stack into memory (8 bytes = REAL8), so into memory that `0x40E579BDE0000000` is written, which, when loaded back into FPU, is 43981.93359375. To output this, you will have to write the opposite conversion, doing divisions/remainders with the base... Check x86/x87 FP instructions/tutorials to get idea. It's not simple for short answer.

Comment: Thanks man @Ped7g. I have a lab today, so I will work on that and try to make it work.